# AKFFTTap goes out of sync in IOS app, how to fix?

Tags: audiokit

When using a live audio source for the AKFFTTap like the microphone, the fft data is perfectly in sync until the app goes into the background and then returns. The fft data becomes several seconds delayed from from the live input from that point on. Is there a way to reset some pointer or reinit when this happens so that the fft is reading from the most recent sample window?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that seems to fix the problem is to get a notification for UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification and then call AudioKit.stop() and then call AudioKit.start() for UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification. I'm not sure if this would be the recommended fix as I'm new to AudioKit. Maybe someone else has a better solution.